# Getting Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected Token ':'

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, get, syntax-error

I'm making an API request and I can't figure out why this keeps happening.

When I check the network tab the data that I requested is correct but It won't print it out in the console.

I'm using the Musixmatch API

Any ideas?

```
              $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                data: {
                  "apikey": musixmatch,
                  "q_track": song,
                  "q_artist": artist,
                  "format":"json",
                },
                url: "https://api.musixmatch.com/ws/1.1/matcher.track.get",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function(response)
                {
                  console.log(response);
                }
              });
```

Comment: error at which line?

Comment: The error stems from the **API**, it doesn't return JSONP at all, hence it can't be parsed as such

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it wrong !

The [documentation for the API](https://developer.musixmatch.com/documentation/input-parameters) clearly states that there are three options for the format, JSON, JSONP and XML.

Since you're using clientside code, you want to be using JSONP, but you can't tell jQuery to expect JSONP and then ask the API to return just JSON, you have to change the format option to JSONP as well, so that the API returns that

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  data: {
    "apikey": 'musixmatch',
    "q_track": 'song',
    "q_artist": 'artist',
    "format": "jsonp",
  },
  url: "https://api.musixmatch.com/ws/1.1/matcher.track.get",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  contentType: 'application/json',
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you guys for sorting out this mess!!

Answer (score 1):

Errors in your code:

1. `"format":"json",` there shouldn't be a trailing comma here.
2. Secondly, try removing the following two lines and it should be working:

   ```
   dataType: "jsonp",
   contentType: 'application/json',
   ```

Finally, if the above doesn't work, please try doing:

```
$.getJSON("https://api.musixmatch.com/ws/1.1/matcher.track.get", {
  "apikey": musixmatch,
  "q_track": song,
  "q_artist": artist,
  "format": "json"
}, function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

The above method is the best because it is specifically for getting the JSON output from APIs. This should be the right way to do.

```js
$.getJSON("https://api.musixmatch.com/ws/1.1/matcher.track.get", {
  "apikey": "",
  "q_track": "Hello",
  "q_artist": "Hi",
  "format": "json"
}, function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```